# Persistent cookies are not being shared across subdomains

Tags: cookies, internet-explorer-9, browser-cache

I have 2 asp .net applications running on the same domain (both in staging & production). Application A opens a page from Application B in a popup window. The cookie names for staging and production are different.

But strangely for some users, even though the request is for production, staging cookies are being appended to the request. Is it a cached request being pulled from somewhere? Where the production cookies going? In Application A the cookies are found and they are fine. But Application B is getting the staging/wrong cookies.

Sorry for not sharing any code for confidentiality issues. Here's an example:

In application A, following cookies are there:

```
BDT, path="/", domain=".sample.com" (this is production)
```

In application B, cookies are somewhat like this:

```
SBDT, path="/", domain=".sample.com" (this is staging cookie)
```

Is the request being cached (at the machine or some proxy server) and being issued repeatedly? Or can it be some mal-ware/virus?

User is using IE9 (in IE7 mode) on Windows 7

Comment: The domain of staging and production is exactly the same in your sample.  Is that accurate?  What proxy server(s) do you have between the client and staging/production?  (You can check the HTTP request for an X-Forwarded-For HTTP header, which well-behaved proxies will set).

Comment: Thank you @EricJ. for the quick response.
Yes, the domains are the same for both, the server name will vary (like prod.sample.com, stg.sample.com).

I already checked, there are no XFF headers in the request.

We got the httpwatch logs from the user.

Comment: If possible, set your cookie to the specific subdomain prod.sample.com or stg.sample.com.  Use a configuration file or similar to tell the software which subdomain to set the cookie on.

Answer (score 0):

finally we cracked it.
We again carefully analyzed the HttpWatch logs and noticed that, the App B is being run in IE protected mode, where as App A is not.

We requested the client to clear the cache and launch the applications again. After that we found that,

> App B is getting NO cookies at all

We made a guess that, they are running in IE protected mode with High security level enabled. And they have ONLY 'App A' in the trusted sites list i.e `AppA.sample.com`

We requested them to add `*.sample.com` instead and that FIXED the issue.

For more details check:
[Persistent cookies are not shared between Internet Explorer and Office applications](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932118/)